# Why my app crashes when I parse string (from EditText) to Float

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, android-edittext

**Why Am I not able to convert String (taken from EditText) to Float.**

I was building a simple app to calculate (addition, subtraction, division, multiplication) of two numbers as per the radio group selection.
But, As I extract string using

```
String temp =  editText.getText().toString();
```

and then try to convert it back into Float in order to perform operation on it

```
num1 = Float.parseFloat(temp);
```

This very line of code causes some error which crashes my app.
I tried to surround it with try-catch which prevented crashing of my app but String was still not parsing into Float.

**Complete Java Code for Calculator App**

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    float ans;
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    float num1, num2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.first_number);
        String temp =  editText.getText().toString();
        try{
            num1 = Float.parseFloat(temp);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate: Still Not Working", e);
        }
        editText = findViewById(R.id.second_number);
        try{
            num2 = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate: String unable to Assign.", e);
        }
        textView = findViewById(R.id.answer);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                caluclate(num1, num2);
                if(num2 == 0 && checkedId == R.id.div){
                    textView.setText("N.A.");
                }else{
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    float addition(float n1, float n2){
        return n1 + n2;
    }
    float subtraction(float n1, float n2){
        return n1 - n2;
    }
    float multiplication(float n1, float n2){
        return n1 * n2;
    }
    float division(float n1, float n2){
        return n1/n2;
    }

    void caluclate(float n1, float n2){
        switch(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.add:
                ans = addition (n1, n2);
                break;
            case R.id.sub:
                ans = subtraction(n1, n2);
                break;
            case R.id.mul:
                ans = multiplication(n1, n2);
                break;
            case R.id.div:
                ans = division(n1, n2);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**XML Code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DFDFDF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="First Number"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="Enter Here"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Second Number"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/second_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="Enter Here"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Choose Operation"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Addition" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Subtraction" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/mul"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Multiplication" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/div"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Division" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Answer"
        android:textColor="#2196F3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*My app was crashing until I comment out that line which assigns String to float
then I tried using try-catch block but this just prevented my app from crashing*

Comment: You read the text within the `onCreate()` method. That means that your `EditText` controls probably are still empty (the user had no time yet to enter anything) and `Float.parseFloat()` fails because what should the numerical value of an empty string be? To fix it you must move the reading of the `EditText` contents and the parsing into the `onCheckedChanged()` handler.

Comment: You logged the error in your code, but didn't add that to your question. If you ever have an issue again it's recommended that you include the error message.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKläger for Explaining this issue

Comment: Does the same happens when some one assign audio to Media player in `onCreate()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here you go**

you should get value from edittext at runtime when action perform,not at creating activity.

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    float ans;
    EditText editText1,editText2;
    TextView textView;
    float num1, num2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //make sure that you entered value contains float,not other data type

        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.first_number); 
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.second_number);
        
        textView = findViewById(R.id.answer);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                try{
                    num1 = Float.parseFloat(editText1.getText().toString()); //i'm getting value here
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate: Still Not Working", e);
                }
                try{
                    num2 = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());//i'm getting value here
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate: String unable to Assign.", e);
                }

                caluclate(num1, num2);
                if(num2 == 0 && checkedId == R.id.div){
                    textView.setText("N.A.");
                }else{
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    float addition(float n1, float n2){
        return n1 + n2;
    }
    float subtraction(float n1, float n2){
        return n1 - n2;
    }
    float multiplication(float n1, float n2){
        return n1 * n2;
    }
    float division(float n1, float n2){
        return n1/n2;
    }

    void caluclate(float n1, float n2){
        switch(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.add:
                ans = addition (n1, n2);
                break;
            case R.id.sub:
                ans = subtraction(n1, n2);
                break;
            case R.id.mul:
                ans = multiplication(n1, n2);
                break;
            case R.id.div:
                ans = division(n1, n2);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please also explain what changes you have done,  what was the issue in the question and why your answer should work.  Your answer might be correct but it's doesn't show how it fixed the query and doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, got your point.

Comment: Glad to hear this!